# Environment - strange behaviour

Tags: macros, environments

I have this document:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{example}[section]
\newenvironment{example}[1][]{\refstepcounter{example}\par\medskip
   \noindent \textbf{Example~\theexample. #1} \rmfamily}{\medskip}
   
\begin{document}

\begin{example}
Test
\end{example}

\end{document}
```

The output looks like this:

[image]

However, if I remove [] (appearing after [1]) in the definition of the enviroment, I'll get

[image]

Can anyone explain to me why this is happening and what those braces [] after [1] actually do, please?

Comment: The `\newenvironment{example}[1][]{}{}` means optional argument, enclosed in `[ ]`, i.e. `\begin{example}[foo]...\end{foo}` , if you remove `[]` from the definition, `[1]` means that the environment expects an argument, it grabs the first token it gets, i.e. the **T** from `Test`: `\begin{example} Test\end{example}`. You should read some introduction about `macro` and/or environments and their arguments with `{}` and `[]` ;-)

Comment: Just a comment aside: why don't you use a theorem-like structure?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I have read [this](https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Environments). And it's still confusing. For example, their "boxed" enviroment doesn't have [] after [1] and it seems it's working well.

Comment: @PatrikBak: The linked example does have multiple versions of `boxed` environments. The first `boxed` does not have a `[1]` at all -- it does not expect an argument, the second example is defined with `[1]` and uses `Title of the Box` as argument, which is centered outside the box frame. Your code usage above should read like this: `\begin{example}[My nice example] Test \end{example}`, if you persist on the `[1][]` usage and it should read `\begin{example}{My nice example} Test\end{example}` in the `[1]` case. I doubt that you want `Test` to be the title of your example environment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's nothing strange about the environment definition really -- the strangeness is the consequence of disregarding LaTeX macro/environment call syntax.

Using standard LaTeX macros like `\newenvironment` there are basically four ways of defining the `example` environment:

- Use no argument at all, i.e. `\newenvironment{foo}{start code}{end code}`
- Use a mandatory argument, that must be enclosed with a `{}` pair:

  `\newenvironment{foobar}[1]{start code}{end code}`
- Use at least one optional argument in definition and decide on environment usage whether the argument is given or not:

  `\newenvironment{foobarother}[1][]{start code}{end code}`

  The empty `[]` means empty optional argument value, i.e. if `\begin{foobarother}` is used without `[]` the `#1` is empty, otherwise specify it as `\begin{foobarother}[Foobar]`.

If a default title should be used, say 'My nice default title', then use 
`\newenvironment{foobarother}[1][My nice default title]{start code}{end code}` which applies `My nice default title` if there's no optional argument specified.

- Use optional and mandatory arguments, i.e. `\newenvironment{yetanotherfoobar}[2][]{start code}{end code}` with `\begin{yetanotherfoobar}[Some other title]{Yet another foobar}`, where `[...]` is **optional**

More sophisticated ways are possible with `\NewEnviron` from `environ` package and `\NewDocumentEnvironment` from `xparse` (for example). Please note that `#1` etc. can't be used in the `end code` of an environment defined with `\newenvironment`, but `\NewDocumentEnvironment` and `\NewEnviron` allow usage of the parameters in the end code section of the environment.

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcounter{example}[section]
\newenvironment{examplewithoptarg}[1][]{\refstepcounter{example}\par\medskip
  \noindent \textbf{Example~\theexample.\notblank{#1}{~#1}{}} \rmfamily}{\medskip}

\newenvironment{examplewitharg}[1]{\refstepcounter{example}\par\medskip
   \noindent \textbf{Example~\theexample. #1} \rmfamily}{\medskip}


\newenvironment{examplewithoutargument}{\refstepcounter{example}\par\medskip
   \noindent \textbf{Example~\theexample} \rmfamily}{\medskip}


\begin{document}

\begin{examplewithoptarg}% Empty optional argument
Test
\end{examplewithoptarg}

% Non-empty optional argument, title is My nice title
\begin{examplewithoptarg}[My nice title] 
Test
\end{examplewithoptarg}

% Correct syntax for example with arg: Use `{Foo}` as argument and `Foo` as title, `Test` is the environment body content
\begin{examplewitharg}{Foo}
Test
\end{examplewitharg}

% 'Wrong' usage -- grabs F, regards it as title and then displays oo Test
\begin{examplewitharg}
Foo Test
\end{examplewitharg}

% No argument -- this has the standard title `Example \theexample` by definition
\begin{examplewithoutargument}
Test
\end{examplewithoutargument}



\end{document}
```

[image]